Which U.S. Administration has had the most Cabinet nominees fail the Senate Confirmation process?
My research says, John Tyler Administration (1841–1845):  with four of his nominees failing to secure confirmation.

Caleb Cushing (Secretary of the Treasury):
Nominated three times in early 1843 to replace Walter Forward as Secretary of the Treasury.  The Senate rejected his nomination three times in a single week.

David Henshaw (Secretary of the Navy):
Served as an interim appointee but was formally nominated in 1843.  His nomination was rejected due to political opposition within the Senate.

James Porter (Secretary of War):
Nominated to replace John Bell, who had resigned in 1841.
Like Henshaw, Porter served as an interim appointee but was rejected when formally nominated in 1843.
His rejection was due to political disagreements

James S. Green (Secretary of the Treasury):
Nominated in 1844 but rejected by the Senate.
Green's nomination was part of Tyler's continuing struggles with a Senate dominated by his political adversaries.


Honorable mention:

Barack Obama Administration (2009–2017) with 2:

Tom Daschle (Nominee for Secretary of Health and Human Services): Daschle withdrew his nomination after revelations that he owed over $128,000 in back taxes and had failed to report significant consulting fees
Bill Richardson (Nominee for Secretary of Commerce): withdrew his nomination amid a federal grand jury investigation into a potential "pay-to-play" scheme


Donald Trump Administration (2017–2021): with 2

Andrew Puzder (Nominee for Secretary of Labor): Puzder withdrew his nomination amid resurfaced allegations of domestic abuse and controversies regarding his business practices.
Ronny Jackson (Nominee for Secretary of Veterans Affairs): Jackson withdrew following allegations of improper conduct, including overprescribing medications and creating a hostile work environment.




What are we counting?  Initial nominations, jettisoned before a formal vote?  Or rejections during a vote?  Would Matt Gaetz count here?

@ItalianPhilosopher,  To my mind Matt Gaetz would count.  Withdrawing because you don't have the support is to my mind equivalent to not having the support in the Senate.

Wikipedia, Unsuccessful nominations to the Cabinet of the United States

President John Tyler holds the record for most cabinet nominees rejected by the Senate; four of his nominees failed to win confirmation.

The unsuccessful nominations occurred in 1843 and 1844 when the Whig party held the Senate majority. Though President Tyler was also a Whig, there were disagreements; so much so that Tyler was expelled from the party.

He believed that the president, rather than Congress, should set policy, and he sought to bypass the Whig establishment led by Senator Henry Clay. Almost all of Tyler's cabinet resigned shortly into his term and the Whigs expelled him from the party and dubbed him "His Accidency".


Was the Senate under control of the president's or opposition party (if those formally existed at the time)?
